# Put two firebase projects (to be more specific, two different realtime databases) from the same account in a flutter project

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-web

I have a flutter web project called "twoaccountfirebasedifferentinjustproject" (I created this project just to solve the question in this topic), this one is on my github(https://github.com/luciano-da-cruz-jr/twoaccountfirebasedifferentinjustproject) and will be available for anyone who wants to use the solution when it is found. Initial image of the running project:

[image]

I created a firebase account, along with this account I created two projects:
-twoaccountfirebaseone
-twoaccountfirebasetwo
Each project has a firebase service being used, in this case, a realtime database in each one.

What I need is to be able to use the realtime database in a single project, in this case, in the project: "twoaccountfirebasedifferentinjustproject". The realtime database of "twoaccountfirebaseone" is already configured by "flutter configure", which already created the file "google-services.json" and the file "firebase_options.dart" for me automatically, I only needed to change the "main.dart" to stay like this:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: const MyApp(),
    ),);
}
```

This way I can already access and manipulate the realtime database of the "twoaccountfirebaseone" project. As we can see in lines 61 to 70 of the "main.dart" file:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;

final date = DateTime.now().toString();
final timenow = date.split('.');

final DBRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('example/'+timenow[0]);

await DBRef.set({
  'timenow': timenow[0],
});
```

Result:

[image]

In this case above inserting random information! And in the case below, deleting the entire database (codes from the file "main.dart", line: 89 to 96):

```
 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;

 final date = DateTime.now().toString();
 final timenow = date.split('.');

 final DBRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('/');

 await DBRef.set(null);
```

Result:

[image]

In this project I want to add the realtime database of "twoaccountfirebasetwo", accessing and manipulating it together with the realtime database "twoaccountfirebaseone" that is already configured and working.

I know I would need to create an instance of the second realtime database related to the "twoaccountfirebasetwo" project but I don't know how to do it. I believe that I need to create another "firebase_options.dart" but I also don't know how to do it and finally I also believe that I would need to create or merge the "google-services.json" file that I also don't know how to do. Could someone help me and also let me know what documentation and how the solution was reached, I'm learning and would like to improve myself in finding solutions. I didn't find or understand anything in the documentation that could help me.

If the question is not well formulated, I will be available to change it. Thank you all in advance.

I Tried:

So Frank, of the steps 1 until 4 i believe to have undertood:

[image]

In the step 5, would it be something like this?

[image: insira a descrição da imagem aqui]

Git https://github.com/luciano-da-cruz-jr/twoaccountfirebasedifferentinjustproject update.

Could someone please help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use only English in posts on this site. And please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

If you have two separate Firebase projects and you want to use the Realtime Database of both in a single app, the simplest way I can think of is to:

1. Generate a `firebase_options.dart` file for the first Firebase project, as you've already done.
2. Rename that file to something like `firebase_options1.dart`.
3. Generate another `firebase_options.dart` file for the second Firebase project.
4. Rename that file to something like `firebase_options2.dart`.
5. Modify the generated dart code so that the variables have unique names.
6. Import both of these options files into the `main.dart`, and call `initializeApp` for both of them.
7. Then access the database for the correct `FirebaseApp` as needed, like is shown in the last code sample in the documentation on [initializing the Firebase Realtime Database package](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/start).

---

If might be worth considering if the databases really should be part of separate projects, or if you actually just want multiple databases in the same project. The latter is possible when you upgrade your Firebase project to the paid plan, at which point you can have multiple databases on a single project each with its own unique URL. If you choose this approach, you can reuse the same `FirebaseApp` object and then pass the database URL to the `FirebaseDatabase` constructor.

Comment: Hi Frank, first of all thank you! Excuse me, because I still don't understand well, I'm a beginner developer.

I will continue my answer below because I get to use images.

Comment: If you're new to this, consider if you really should be trying to access two Firebase databases in your application to begin with.  Why not simplify matters and start with a single database, and only look at the more complex scenario of accessing another database once you have the single-database access working?

Comment: I agree with you Frank, but I'm looking for this solution to help a friend. He used a low code framework to create an application, and in this application he placed several realtime databases from different projects. He doesn't use flutter and doesn't know how to use it, so I'm making a new version of his application with flutter and in this part I got stuck, I feel that the solution is not that complex and that there is a way to solve it. Above I edited the question with the solution I tried following your instructions.